# Access Lookup Field With SalesforceSharp

Tags: salesforce, force.com

How can I query a lookup field in SalesforceSharp?  When I run this query:

```
SELECT id,
AccountId,
Contact.Account.peaksyn_mm__Member_Family__c
From Contact limit 2
```

in Force.com's Developer Console, peaksyn_mm__Member_Family__c is "Y" or "N". But when I run the query with SalesforceSharp

```
var contact_records = client.Query<SFContact>(@"SELECT id,
AccountId,
Contact.Account.peaksyn_mm__Member_Family__c
From Contact limit 2");

foreach (var r in contact_records)
{
    Console.Log( r.id + ": " + (r.peaksyn_mm__Member_Family__c == null).ToString() );
}
```

with this class

```
public class SFContact
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public string peaksyn_mm__Member_Family__c { get; set; }
}
```

r.peaksyn_mm__Member_Family__c is null for every record. Is there a syntax I need to access the field in the Account object?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use r.account.peaksyn_mm__Member_Family__c instead of r.peaksyn_mm__Member_Family__c

Comment: That did it.  I modified the SFContact class to:

public class SFContact
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public string AccountId { get; set; }
    public SFAccount account { get; set; }
}

to access the property